# How to check if all values is not None in dict continent list and dict with different format

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop

I want to check if dict contains value None knowing that the format is not unique it can the dict content other dict and other list contain dict You can see the example :

```
{
    "first_name": "test",
    "last_name": "test",
    "cars": [
        {"mark": "test", "type": "12"},
        {"mark": "test2", "type": "7"},
    ],
    "date_created": "2022-05-07",
    "invoice_info": {
        "price": 1233,
        "currency": "EUR",
        "date": [
            {"date_1": "2022-05-07", "info": {"comment": "test", "place": "France"}},
            {"date_2": "2022-06-12", "info": {"comment": None, "place": "France"}},
        ]

    }
}
```

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a recursive function. If the function receives a dictionary or a list, it loops through the values - otherwise compares the value to `None`. Here is a quick example:

```
data = {"foo": "bar"}

def includes_none(node):
    if isinstance(node, dict):
        for _, v in node.items():
            if includes_none(v):
                return True
    elif isinstance(node, list):
        for v in node:
            if includes_none(v):
                return True
    else:
        if node is None:
            return True
    return False

print(includes_none(data))
```

Comment: The different cases could be simplified to `return any(includes_none(v) for v in node.values())` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Minimum code here ;) returns True if finds None in dict or list values (recursive)

```
def seekNone(node):
    if (isinstance(node, dict) or isinstance(node, list)):
        try:
            node = node.values()
        except: 
            pass
        for val in node:
            if seekNone(val):
                return True
    return node is None


print(seekNone(your_dict_here))
```

Comment: [Please do not post an answer that consists essentially of
code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer). Please [edit] your
answer to include an explanation of how and why the code solves the problem,
when it should be used, what its limitations are, and if possible a link to
relevant documentation.